# Отключение кэша в конфигурационном файле ehcache.xml

Tags: java, spring, кэширование, ehcache

Всем доброго дня. Помогите решить проблему: возможно ли отключить кэш спринга в конфигурационном файле ehcache.xml?
Имеется файл конфигурации кэша ehcache.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd">    

<cache-template name="expiryCache">
    <expiry>
        <ttl unit="minutes">5</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">5000</heap>
</cache-template>

<cache alias="geatewayCache" uses-template="expiryCache"/>
```

Чтобы аннотация @Cacheable была, но кэш при этом не работал: например задать такой template при котором кэш не будет использоваться (предпочтительно). Задать время хранения и количество элементов в кэше равное нулю недопустимо.
Везде только пишут как сконфигурировать кэш, но вот как его отключить не нашёл. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? 
P.S. на худой конец, как игнорировать конкретно аннотации @Cacheable и @CacheEvict?

Answer (score 0):

Просто поменяйте реализацию бина `CacheManager` на `NoOpCacheManager`.

Comment: Но как мне сделать подмену в конкретном классе? Что бы в одних классах использовался мой рабочий кэш менеджер, а в других NoOpCacheManager. Через профили не получилось ведь мне надо сразу два разных бина менеджеров.

Answer (score 0):

@Qualifier(name = "id бина нужного менеджера кэша")CacheManager cacheManager